How to migrate the storagemap into storagedoublemap through runtime upgrade?
Whenever i try to do runtime upgrade within the pallet which has storagemap and then I replace it with storagedoublemap, it removes all the data present in the storagemap. How can i migrate this data ?. I've already checked the basic migration but it only make the change in value of the storage. How can i perform it keys?

You can use storage_key_iter.
// If your storage map is `Twox64Concat(AccountId) => u128`.
type K = AccountId;
type T = u128;
type H = Twox64Concat;

for (k, v) in storage_key_iter::<K, T, H>(b"PalletName", b"ItemName").drain() {
  <NewStorageDoubleMap<T>>::insert(?, k, v);
}

Tip: if you want to keep the old storage, delete the .drain().
Tiptip: Only ..Concat hasher is reversible. You can't perform these actions with other hashers. There is no way to migrate those storages using irreversible hashers.
